# PHP break into new line

Tags: php

I have my textarea data called from db, which data expected to show in new line without `<br />` along, how can I break the `<br />` and show in textarea into a new line?

My database column is stored as `hello<br />world` exactly as well.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You should store data in your database, not formatting. Do you want to have the `<br />` or not in your textarea?

Comment: ^ Best answer/comment I read in this thread so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
$text = 'This is some text<br />With a line break in it';

$text = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $text);

// Outputs: 
   This is some text
   with a line break in it
```

Make sure the `\n` parameter in str_replace is between double quotes. It wont work between single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is *NOT* store HTML inside your database in the first place.

1. Store text in the database, keeping newlines as `"\n"`.
2. Upon rendering on the page, use `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))`.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
str_replace('<br />', PHP_EOL, 'hello<br />world')
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is only for new lines, you can use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

```
$text = str_ireplace("<br />", "\n", $text);
$text = str_ireplace("<br>", "\n", $text);
```

Answer (score -1):

What I like to do is defining multi-line strings in arrays like that:

```
$output = array();
$output[] = 'Hello<br />';
$output[] = 'World.<br />';
$output[] = '<br />';
$output[] = 'This is a test.';

echo implode("\r\n", $output);
```

This will return the HTML code:

```
Hello<br />
World.<br />
<br />
This is a test.
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `urlencode` and `urldecode` which I use for a similar thing, for example:

Store your data in the database like this:

```
$html       = urlencode($_POST['content']);
```

with a normal query like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (Content) VALUES ('".$html."')
```

And then get it out of the DB using this:

```
$strSQL1    ="SELECT Content FROM table;
$objQuery1  = mysql_query($strSQL1);
$objResult1     = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); 

$show       = urldecode($objResult1["Content"]);
```

And then populate the textarea with this:

```
<textarea name="content"><?php echo "$show"?></textarea>
```

Answer (score -2):

The way I do this in HTML5 is by putting a lot of spaces between line 1 and line 2.

It's a little bit of a dirty hack, but it works.

```
<textarea rows="8" placeholder="Line 1                                     
                                                                        Line 2
                                                                        Line 3"></textarea>
```

Storing this many white-spaces in your database might not be ideal but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: As you say storing not needed white-spaces in your database is not ideal. So why using an inefficient solution if there are much better approaches (already posted here). Working code != good code